# Rotating proxies mechanize for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, proxy, mechanize-ruby

Is there a way to get Mechanize to use multiple proxies or rotate proxies for each request?

```
agent.set_proxy(addr, port, user = nil, pass = nil)
```

sets up a proxy, is there a way I could set this to change during each request?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you dont plan to use the same agent for each request, yes. You could develop a Helper class that uses a simple randomizer of various user agent strings, and hosts provided by your proxy.

```rb
class ProxyMeshHelper

  def initialize
  end

  def ex
    return {
      host: host_randomizer,
      port: port,
      proxy_user: proxy_user,
      proxy_pass: proxy_pass,
      user_agent_alias: user_agent_randomizer
    }
  end

  def host_randomizer
    host_arr.sample
  end

  def host_arr
    ['us-tx.proxy.com', 'us-nc.proxy.com'...etc]
  end

  def user_agent_randomizer
    user_agents.sample
  end

  def user_agents
    ["Linux Firefox", "Linux Konqueror", "Linux Mozilla", "Mac Firefox", "Mac Mozilla", "Mac Safari 4", "Mac Safari", "Windows Chrome", "Windows Edge", "Windows Mozilla", "Windows Firefox", "iPhone", "Android"]
  end

  def port
    ENV['proxy_port_number']
  end

  def proxy_user
    ENV['proxy_mesh_username']
  end

  def proxy_pass
    ENV['proxy_mesh_password']
  end

  def proxy_mesh_mechanize_template
    proxy = AppMaps::ProxyMeshHelper.new.ex
    agent = Mechanize.new { |agent|
      agent.user_agent_alias = proxy[:user_agent_alias]
    }
    agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
    agent.set_proxy(proxy[:host], proxy[:port], proxy[:proxy_user], proxy[:proxy_pass])
    agent
  end

end
```